# Excel VLOOKUP if Contains

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to write an Excel formula that will use lets say whatever the user types into B2, searches another sheets first column for a row that CONTAINS that number and brings back the second column.

I've tried this vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&B3&"*",[MPI_Directory_by_Establishment_NumberWEBSITE.xls]AllMPIByEstNo!$1:$65536,2)
```

Also this Index Match -- it only brings back exact match

```
=INDEX([MPI_Directory_by_Establishment_NumberWEBSITE.xls]AllMPIByEstNo!$B:$B,MATCH(B2,[MPI_Directory_by_Establishment_NumberWEBSITE.xls]AllMPIByEstNo!$A:$A,0))
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I feel like you should specify the range that you're searching for the number in.  Instead of `$1:$65536` use `$A$1:$B$65536`.  There may also be a type mismatch here, but I'd try that to start.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally need FALSE as the 4th argument of VLOOKUP, e.g. To simplify with data on sheet2

> =VLOOKUP("*"&B2&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)

But is the matching value (in column A) a number or alphanumeric?

Comment: the fields are in number format: General. It's a mix of alphanumeric and numer